# How does Nginx handle `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` headers when configured as a reverse proxy cache?

Tags: nginx, caching, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-304

I have a PHP CMS as an upstream/origin server that serves content. It is placed behind a Nginx web server configured as a reverse proxy cache with `proxy_pass` and `proxy_cache`.

While implementing `304 Not Modified` response on the upstream/origin server, I noticed that I sometimes get `304 Not Modified` response from the proxy without my upstream/origin server being called.

My proxy configuration looks like this (notice that I don't cache 304 responses):

```
http {
  #...
  proxy_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;
}

server {
  server_name _;
  
  #...

  location / {
    proxy_cache microcache;
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
    #...
    proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1m;
    proxy_pass http://upstream;
  }
}
```

When hitting a URL for the first time, I get a `200` with a `X-Cache-Status: MISS` and the `ETag` and `Last-Modified` headers returned by the origin.

The second time I hit the URL, I get a `X-Cache-Status: HIT` and my origin doesn't get called, so all is great!

However, if I hit the URL again, this time with the `If-Modified-Since` and `If-None-Match` headers with the values received with the first call, I get a `304 Not Modified`, with `X-Cache-Status: HIT` and still no call on my origin server!

I seems then that Nginx has the content in its cache, and figures with the incoming headers that it should return a 304. Meaning my origin never gets to return the 304 itself if the content is in the Nginx cache.

Am I right? I cannot find any documentation on this behavior. I, however found a module in the Nginx source code that seems the be handling something similar: https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/src/http/modules/ngx_http_not_modified_filter_module.c#L78

Could you please provide me with insights on this behavior, how it works, and what enables it in my configuration?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
proxy_cache_path /usr/share/nginx/cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcache:10m max_size=1024m inactive=1h;

proxy_cache microcache;
```

Meaning that nginx server stores cache data to `/usr/share/nginx/cache/`

and

```
proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 1m;
```

This means any HTTP API calls that have HTTP statuses 200, 301, or 302 use nginx local cache (which is stored in `/usr/shre/nginx/cache`) for one minute.